# How to embed json with html control character entites in the html and let js consume that?

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have a use case where I need to embed the json in the html and let the javascript read it. An example is something like this:

```
<head></head>
<body>
    <div id="foo">{"foo": "bar&#xd;"}</div>
    <script>
        var a = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('foo').innerHTML);
        console.log(a);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Notice the json has the carriage return in it `&#xd;` and because html parser will convert the entities back to their original character, the inner html that javascript gets will contain the literal newline character, which breaks the json parse function call.

The solutions I could have:

1. wrap the content in CDATA
2. wrap the content in script tag (this would produce error from the parser saying the syntax is not valid but seems to be working regardless)

Question is: Are these approaches okay? If these are not best practice, what approach should be used here?

Comment: try `.textContent` instead of `.innerHTML`

Comment: that doesn't make any difference

Comment: ahh, i see. well, you could use `<script type=fake>` to snuff the syntax error.

Comment: You say _"**cartridge** return"_ then use `&#xc;` which is `0x0c` which is a FormFeed character.  If you meant _"**carriage** return"_, that is `0x0d`. I guess what control character it actually is is irrelevant to the problem, but it has already led to some confusion.

Comment: @StephenP oh sry for those silly mistakes. I think i typed carriage wrong and auto correction then changed it to cartridge.

Answer (score 0):

Encode the `&` with the entity `&amp;`. And use `textContent` to get the raw content, without re-encoding the `&` as an entity.

```js
var a = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('foo').textContent);
alert(JSON.stringify(a));
console.log(a);
```

```html
<div id="foo">{"foo": "bar&amp;#xc;"}</div>
```

Comment: what if the original string contains `&amp;`? it gets unintentionally decoded into an `&`

Comment: You need to change that to `&amp;amp;`. All `&` that you want to treat literally need to be encoded.

Answer (score 0):

Embed the content in a `<script>` tag and make an assignment **inside** the script tag.

You won't get any error (if the JSON is valid) and you don't even need to parse the JSON as it will be parsed by the javascript interpreter.

By the way, I'm not sure you're escaping the linefeed correctly; I'd suggest `\n` or `\u000`

```
<head></head>
<body>
    <script>
        var foo = {"foo": "bar\n"};
    </script>
    <script>
        // do whatever with `foo`
        var a = foo;
        console.log(a);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The only drawbacks with this approach is that you set a variable in the global namespace and you can't edit the content of the script as you would do with an html node.

Comment: `&#xc` aka `0x0c` is not a CR or LF, it is a FormFeed — but then again _that_ might be a typo from the OP, and I don't know what a _"cartridge"_ return is.

Comment: are you sure? if I type `a="bar&#xc;"; alert(a);` I just get **bar&#xc;** isn't \uxxxx where xxxx is a four digit hex code the only way to escape a unicode character in JSON?

Comment: @Paolo The reason it's happening is because he has the JSON in an HTML DIV. The entity is being decoded as part of parsing the HTML.

Comment: ...still I don't see any reason to put the JSON **inside the html**. If it's an AJAX response it just need to be parsed as is. If it's content statically generated with the HTML page it can be placed inside `<script>` tags. But maybe I'm missing something...